# SQL 2012 full text search sometimes produces unexpected results when searching for single letters

Tags: full-text-search, sql-server-2012

Consider this:

`select * from cats where contains(catname, '"Furry Pudding"')`

It will match entries that contain "Furry Pudding" exactly as it's written.

Next, consider this:

`select * from cats where contains(catname, '"A B C"')`

This should match any cat that is called A B C. It doesn't do any partial matching, and I am confident that it shouldn't.

Now consider this:

`select * from cats where contains(catname, '"A B C Furry Pudding"')`

You'd expect that to only match a cat thats name is "A B C Furry Pudding", but instead it seems to ignore the A B C and produces the same results as the first query.

Can anyone explain why this occurs? It ruins our search if for example we have a cat called Mr. T and it matches every cat that has 'Mr' in it, ignoring the T completely (the search should not do any partial matching, so Mr T should match only cats that have a name which is T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) indicates that when using phrases in Full Text Search; noise words (known as stop words) are removed, such as "A".  In the first example it could be that A is being removed from the search phrase.

To see a list of stopwords; use this [system view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280608.aspx).  It may be that "Mr" is also included in your stop word list if it has been customised.

Have you tried instead to use the AND logical operator with `word` terms instead of phrases to establish that you want all the words to be matched; for example:

```
select * from cats where contains(catname, 'A AND B AND C AND Furry AND Pudding')
```

Comment: So, a combination of two things fixed it. First of all, I disabled the stop list. This meant 'Mr T' would work fine, but was incredibly slow. Secondly, I did the 'AND' comparison for 'Mr' AND 'T' and it worked instantly. I'm not sure what the difference is as it's doing an AND comparison anyway I thought, but it is fast. Also using NEAR(Mr,T) is instant, so it's a perfect solution. Thanks.